# consuming webservices but not able to show data fetched from webservices in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, webservices-client

1. created xml for listview order.xml
2. consuming web services in Webservices.java class

```java
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.admin.gaurav.in/";
//Webservice URL - WSDL File location   
private static String URL = "http://adm.gaurav.in/UserWS?wsdl";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "/";
private static final String METHOD1 = "ordersList";

public static String invokeListViewWS(String userName,String webMethName) {

  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD1);
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

  try {
    // Invoke web service
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+METHOD1, envelope);
    // Get the response
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    String[] list = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];
    for(int i= 0; i< response.getPropertyCount(); i++){
      list[i] = response.getProperty(i).toString(); 
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
    HomeActivity.errored = true;
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "abhi";
}
```

I am trying to fetch method ordersList which is type  and returning a list
I am unable to get that can any one help me with how to get list from webservice, how to store that and populate that in list view. I am new in android development so if anyone have  any link or resources which can help please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are already retrieving strings from response and putting them in a list. Does the list contain the right content when done?

Comment: No compiler doesn't compiles the try block. If u have any reference code to implement list through webservices pls help...

Comment: That is a very different problem as to the subject of your post! You could have started mentioning that. You are using this forum the wrong way.